# How to resolve issue while i'm trying to add android platform to Ionic project?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

please excuse me for the question but when I want to add android to my ionic project I get the error in capture below. Could someone point me in the right direction so that I can resolve this error?[image]

Answer (score 0):

either update your packages the way so they won't have any conflict anymore, or use `--legacy-peer-deps` instead of `--force`.
also provide code and errors in text, image is not easy to read.